# How to hide the checkboxes which donot have given set of classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Suppose I have the following `html` checkboxes:

```
<input class="filters identity0" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity0 identity1 " name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity identity2" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
```

I want to show the checkboxes which have at least one class common in them. The `jQuery` I wrote to achieve this is :

```
$('label:not(:has('filters identity0'))').hide();
```

Now this should hide the first two checkboxes because they have `identity0` in common but it hides all of them. This was an example of what I am trying to do. Any help regarding this would b appreciated.

This is what I am actually doing.

```
$('body').on('change', '.filters', function () {
            if(this.checked){
           var _class=$(this).attr('class');
           $('label:not(:has('+_class+'))').hide();
           console.log(_class);
            }
    });
```

Comment: `:has()` needs valid selectors, so it should be `:has(.filters, .identity0)`, although I'm still not sure the logic is correct without seeing more of your HTML

Comment: I am getting class name dynamically I have updated my question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In which case you'll need to hack around the `class` value so that it's valid to use in `has()`

Comment: How? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Regex would be one way, but I'll be honest that this is a *really* ugly and hacky way of doing what you require. I'd suggest you start a new question being clear about what you want to achieve. Right now this is an XY question about a very poor solution to what I'm sure is a relatively straightforward issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
   .hasClass("identity0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```js
var classToHide = "identity0"

$("input:checkbox").each(function(index, input) {
  if($(input).hasClass(classToHide)) {
    $(input).hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filters identity0" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity0 identity1 " name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity identity2" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
```

Or preferred and simple way:

```js
var classToHide = "identity0"

$("input:checkbox." + classToHide).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="filters identity0" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity0 identity1 " name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
<input class="filters identity identity2" name="filters[Device][]" type="checkbox" value="ipad">
```